# How to just compile templates in Template::Toolkit?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

What's the best way to 'compile only' (so to their Perl compiled version) templates for template toolkit.

So far I've called ->process on them, but as it really execute the templates, that's far from ideal.

Ideally I'd like to 'just compile' templates to their Perl version without evaluating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template#template-name), it is possible like so:

```
my $tt = Template->new;
my $templateFile = "something.html";
my $compiledTemplate = $tt->template($templateFile);
```

Comment: Damn, I missed this one. Thanks!